# How to filter customer voice from customer - agent conversation recordings?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a doubt on the project I'm working now.

Actually I want only customer voice from the recordings which contains customer-agent conversation.But I have no idea to filter customer voice from customer - agent voice recording.

Could someone please share your ideas on this ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the "Cocktail Party Problem". Andrew Ng's machine learning course on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/welcome) gives a solution based on SVD for this problem. See the first week's course notes. Ng refers to Sam Roweis, Yair Weiss & Eero Simoncelli but I can't seem to find the reference on Google Scholar.